# how to write regex for number not starting with 11 in WSDL

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, wsdl

I need a regular expression for WSDL, in which a number should not start with `11`. I'm using the following pattern but it is not working. The number is 4 digit and it should not start with 11.

```
<xsd:pattern value="(?!11)[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following regex:

```
((1[02-9])|([02-9]1)|([02-9][02-9]))[0-9][0-9]
  ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^
  AAAAAAA   BBBBBBB   CCCCCCCCCCCC  DDDDDDDDDD
```

What the partial expressions do:

- `AAA` finds all two digit numbers starting with 1 and not having 1 as the second digit
- `BBB` finds all two digit numbers ending with 1 and not having 1 as the first digit
- `CCC` finds all two digit numbers not containing the digit 1 at all
- `DDD` adds two more digits `0..9` to make it a four digit number

The pipe signs `|` between the expressions `AAA` and `BBB` and `CCC` function as a logical OR.